# Installing MapFish?

Tags: installation, mapfish-print

I have an installation problem with MapFish 3.

I am trying to use the WAR file and it works with every MapFish version <=3.10.8 , but not with the newer ones (>=3.11.0).

My system configuration:
Ubuntu Server 16.04, 
Java 8, 
Tomcat 8

The Spring root WebApplicationContext cannot be initializen in MapFish versions <=3.11.0 and the errors start with the following:

`org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinterFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mapfish-print-printer-factory.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'appsRootDirectory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: servlet:///print-apps does not refer to a file on the current system.
...
...`

Any ideas why the breaking point is version 3.11.0 and how I can use newer versions of MapFish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve it in new installation in version 3.20.3 on Windows 10, create a new folder called 'print-apps' in the root folder alongside 'META-INF' and 'WEB-INF'.

Comment: Working also in Linux and in versions 3.21 and 3.22. The java, Tomcat or OS versions are not the problem.