# Lack of information in Mapfish 3 docs: What is "print configurations"?

Tags: mapfish-print

I'm very new in Mapfish print. After installed a Docker instance from https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/mapfish_print ( version 3.28 ), I can see it running well because I can retrieve some informations from (hart to find out ) its REST endpoints (in this case `/print/fonts` ).

Well.. I've decide to read this https://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/api.html because I think this is the place where the new users will find and go first to find the very basic to start.

But these docs are full of premisses like I'm already know much of thinks.

So... to be short ...

My endpoint `/print/apps.json` returns an empty json array but https://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/api.html tells me there will be a "List available print configurations" data like "simple" and "default".

Being stubborn and trying to access `/print/default/capabilities.json` gives me the error:

```
Error while processing request:

There is no configurationFile registered in the 
org.mapfish.print.servlet.ServletMapPrinterFactory bean with the id: 'default'
```

I didn't find anything about what "print configurations" could be. The docs starts from the premisse I'm already have all up and running configured but don't show how to configure anything (or I can't find it).

I came from Geoserver print plugin because this plugin is an old Mapfish version so I've decided to change to a standalone print server but can't find out how to even print something because the endpoint I was using in Geoserver `pdf/print.pdf` is not here...

I'm completely lost here.

Can someone points me a good place to a new user start from zero knowing nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples are at https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/tree/master/examples/src/test/resources/examples. Take the repo zip https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/archive/refs/heads/master.zip and extract the directories.

Copy each extracted directory to print-apps (and change dirs owner to Java servlet owner)

Restart your server (in my case Tomcat) and you get what you want like below at http://localhost:8080/print/index.html

[image]

PS: hit the error about missing `print-apps` dir in `webapps/print` folder while troubleshooting https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339339/638

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for your answer. Seems close to what I supose to do in my own answer. But I have no "index.html" in my install. I'm using the docker version from here: ```https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/mapfish_print``` (Tag v3.28)

Comment: But despiste this... you're correct so I'll accept this.

Comment: I'll ask you to edit your answer to generalize it. I mean... you tell us just to copy examples but my question was related to what I need to do to create "print configurations". Your answer is correct because solves the problem but I need to deduce it. I think the correct answer mus have something like "You need to create subfolders under print-apps and put there these files: ... " , like you found in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well... by reading this https://github.com/justb4/docker-mapfish-print/tree/master/config I can supose we need to create some folders below `webapps/print-apps/` being the name of each folder the infamous "print configuration" and having its own `config.yaml`

I'll check this as soon as possible and edit here.

Comment: See Thomas answer